# What is the best method for getting the column index from an datagridview in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

There are different methods to get the index of a datagridview column in C#, for example:

```
dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.Index; 
dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.DisplayIndex; 
datagridview1.Columns[column.name].Index;
datagridview1.Columns[column.name].DisplayIndex;
```

The dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1 is inside the DataGridViewColumnsCollection List.

Desingner Code:

```
this.datagridview1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1,
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2,
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3
            }
```

I was experiencing the different methods, but in strange cases I obtain differents values, for example I use this:

```
datagridview1.Columns[dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.name].Index;
```

I get the real index relative to the column collection, in my test the value is 3.

but if I use this:

```
dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.Index;
```

I get a distinct index, in my test the value is 1.

I do not understand that, because in theory is the same property, doesn't it?,

in case of the displayindex property the result is similar. In my datagridview I have invisible and read only columns.

In other tests, I get the correct values for all cases, and this datagridivew contains more visible and invisible columns to.

My question is: what is the best method for get the correct index of the column in a DataGridView, if I use the events, for example CellContentClick to equalize the DataGridViewCellEventArgs.ColumnIndex?

example:

```
private void datagridview1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex.Equals(datagridview1.Columns[dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.Name].Index))
        datagridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.Index].Value = true;
}
```

**UPDATE**

this is my test is a visual studio watch:

TEST 1:

[image]

```
 private void dgvTerminales_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex.Equals(dgvTerminales.Columns[clmActiva.Name].Index))
                dgvTerminales.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[clmEditado.Index].Value = true;
        }
```

TEST 2:

Other datagridview with same properties, columns and form.

[image]

```
private void dgvSucursales_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex.Equals(dgvSucursales.Columns[clmActiva.Name].Index))
                dgvSucursales.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = true;
        }
```

clmActiva is a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column type.

Comment: you need to show where you got `column` from, is that a data table column?

Comment: Are you doing any sorting on the columns that would affect their column index?

Comment: I need to compare the e.ColumnIndex with a specific column index in my DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

***Update # I lost count***

Index

> Gets the relative position of the band within the DataGridView control.
>   The value of this property does not necessarily correspond to the current visual position of the band within the collection. For example, if the user reorders columns in a DataGridView at run time (assuming the AllowUserToOrderColumns property is set to true), the value of the Index property of each column will not change. Instead, the column DisplayIndex values change. Sorting rows, however, does change their Index values.

DisplayIndex

> Gets or sets the display order of the column relative to the currently displayed columns.
>   Unlike the Index property, the DisplayIndex property corresponds to the current position of the column as displayed by the user interface (UI). By default, each column's DisplayIndex is set to numbers of increasing order, which reflects the order in which they were added. The Visible property value does not affect the DisplayIndex value.

**Update**

Ok so it seems the OP left out his exact code which makes this next to impossible to help but after all of the comments in this thread, here goes my next set of results.

The OP is using a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn so in fact by using CellContentClick this is not incorrect. Changing the CheckBox value will properly fire this event.

The order of events fired would follow CellClick, CellContentClick

Now that this is out of the way, Next

Without having your exact code and trying to piece it together I have the following. (Note because I change these names in the designer, if you try to edit it in the UI it causes issues but I was matching what OP provided so as long as these are adjust in designer.cs itself it works fine lol. The visual designer will yell at you trying to use these names)

```
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
this.dataGridViewCheckBoxColumn1,
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2,
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3});
```

So my DataGridView has 1 CheckBox and 2 Text Columns

below registers all values as 0 when I click the first column with the checkbox which is correct. The event will not fire on TextBox columns.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int a = e.ColumnIndex;
    int b = dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridViewCheckBoxColumn1.Name].Index;
    int c = dataGridViewCheckBoxColumn1.Index;

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex.Equals(dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridViewCheckBoxColumn1.Name].Index))
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.Index].Value = true;
}
```

When I change the position of the CheckBox to be the second column in the grid rather than the first. Then the above values register as all 1 which is correct again.

I don't see any issues. Please again provide us with your exact code, controls ...etc. There is still something missing we can't see as there isn't an issue with what you are providing.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is when I use column.Index or datagridview.Columns[column.name].Index,  I get different values in one test but in other test with other datagridview I get same values using the two properties.

Comment: @Chiro300 You have to show us what column is. You aren't so we can't tell you why. Where is column declares, how are you assigning it.

Comment: The column is the object example: DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn/DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, and I use DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index property

Comment: @Chiro300 please update your post and show us this code. In your code above you show column.Name which means column is declared somewhere and you are assigning something to it for use. We really need to see this to help.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly (if you are getting different results),

```
column.Index;
```

Is not pointing to the same instance as:

```
datagridview1.Columns[column.name].Index;
```

To prove it display the `.GetHashCode()` value of both.

Comment: Yes, but in the MSDN description define the column.Index property is the relative position in the datagridview.Columns list,
Therefore I want to understand that  column.Index == datagridview.Columns[column.name].Index, doesn't it?.

Comment: show more of your code, show where you get/create the `column`

Comment: I created the columns in design view in the visual studio.

Comment: looks like one is a data column and the other view

Comment: and what is the data source of the dgv?

Comment: the data source is a List<Object> the Object contains 4 properties, example: datagridview1.DataSource = List<Object>

Comment: if they were the same instance then `.Index` would return the same value, but it's not.

Comment: if they both return the SAME instance then why would `.Index` return a different value?

Comment: why is it out of the realm of possibility that this guy is not comparing the same columns but thinks he is?

Comment: they may be the same column `Name` but NOT the SAME.

Comment: Its the same column, but the .Index properties it's different but the values are same in a correct case, but in this case return different values. I don't know why...

Comment: you compared both .GetHashCode() values?

Comment: see what this does: `bool same = (column.GetHashCode() ==datagridview1.Columns[column.name].GetHashCode() )`

Comment: @TMcKeown The GetHashCode it's different

Comment: that's because they are different objects.  Thank you for verifying.